# How to manage dependencies with git?

Tags: git, dependencies, repository

I am new to online open source projects. I have cloned a repo, but there are certain dependencies that I need to run the code. How do I find/download them?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what those dependencies are and  what your platform is.  You need to be way more specific for this to be a useful question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Git is useful for version control and generally not suited for dependency management. If this was node.js, for example, you could specify your dependencies within `package.json`. From there, you could install them with `npm install`.

Thus, how you manage your dependencies will change depending on what stack you're using.